# How do you change the notification duration in Apple macOS 11 / Big Sur

Tags: macos, terminal, notifications, big-sur

How do I change the time of how long a notification stays on the screen in macOS 11 Big Sur?
There's no setting for this in the system preferences.

I macOS Catalina the following command in Terminal worked (followed by a re-login to the system), whereas the number at the end of the command determined the number of seconds the notification stayed on the screen:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime -int 2
```

In earlier versions of macOS the command looked like this:

```
defaults write com.apple.notificationcenterui bannerTime 2
```

None of these commands seems to work on macOS 11 Big Sur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the output of `defaults read com.apple.notificationcenterui` it appears that specific preference domain key is no longer available. Additionally, [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/sz4lq0/notification_center_banner_time_can_no_longer_be/) seems to say the same thing.

I'm *guessing* that Apple removed this key (along with a lot of other `com.apple.notificationcenterui` preference keys given that the domain now only contains `last-analytics-stamp` and `widgets`) around the same time that they introduced managing Notification Center configurations via MDM (see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/notifications) because a user-defined `bannerTime` (if it were set to, say, `0`) could in theory interfere/override with a MDM administrator's defined settings for how Notification Center notification banners are presented.